# How to remove soft link to directory?

Tags: symlink

```
[murphy@eva02 playg]$ ls -l
total 12
drwxrwxr-x. 2 murphy murphy 4096 Jul 22 14:02 dir1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 murphy murphy    4 Jul 22 14:03 dir1-sym -> dir1
drwxrwxr-x. 2 murphy murphy 4096 Jul 22 14:02 dir2
-rw-r--r--. 3 murphy murphy 2690 Jul 22 13:59 fun
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 murphy murphy    3 Jul 22 14:01 fun-sym -> fun
[murphy@eva02 playg]$ rm -i fun
rm: remove regular file 'fun'? y
[murphy@eva02 playg]$ ls -l
total 8
drwxrwxr-x. 2 murphy murphy 4096 Jul 22 14:02 dir1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 murphy murphy    4 Jul 22 14:03 dir1-sym -> dir1
drwxrwxr-x. 2 murphy murphy 4096 Jul 22 14:02 dir2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 murphy murphy    3 Jul 22 14:01 fun-sym -> fun
[murphy@eva02 playg]$ rm fun-sym dir1-sym/
rm: cannot remove 'dir1-sym/': Is a directory
[murphy@eva02 playg]$ ls -l
total 8
drwxrwxr-x. 2 murphy murphy 4096 Jul 22 14:02 dir1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 murphy murphy    4 Jul 22 14:03 dir1-sym -> dir1
drwxrwxr-x. 2 murphy murphy 4096 Jul 22 14:02 dir2
[murphy@eva02 playg]$ rm -f dir1-sym/
rm: cannot remove 'dir1-sym/': Is a directory
[murphy@eva02 playg]$ rm -r dir1-sym/
rm: cannot remove 'dir1-sym/': Not a directory
[murphy@eva02 playg]$ rm -rf dir1-sym/
[murphy@eva02 playg]$ ls -l
total 8
drwxrwxr-x. 2 murphy murphy 4096 Jul 22 14:04 dir1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 murphy murphy    4 Jul 22 14:03 dir1-sym -> dir1
drwxrwxr-x. 2 murphy murphy 4096 Jul 22 14:02 dir2
```

While `fun` and `fun-sym` are removed easily ... is not the same with `dir1-sym`? How can I remove it?

Ps. This is part of a book exercise. I guess it is wrong...

Comment: I just want to point out that the book is not wrong. There is no slash. I guess the slash came from a previous command in the history...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omit the slash:

```
rm dir1-sym
```

That will remove the symlink.